# pine editor Skip to the bottom line 2 times with "\n"

Tags: pine-script, pine-editor

use the "\n" command to the bottom line. But I want to go down two lines using "\n" command.

For example

```
//@version=4
Message = "tp: " +tostring(tp) + "\n" + "cross 20x"
```

This code will output like this

```
Tp: 20
Cross 20x
```

But I want it to look like this

```
Tp: 20

Cross 20x
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another '\n' to wrap multiple lines:

```
//@version=4
study("'\n'")

tp = 10
Message = "tp: " +tostring(tp) + "\n" + "\ncross 20x"

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, Message)
```

[image]